# Get all combinations of several columns in a pandas dataframe and calculate sum for each combination

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 
                   'colA': [1, 2, 3, 4], 
                   'colB': [5, 6, 7, 8], 
                   'colC': [9, 10, 11, 12], 
                   'colD': [13, 14, 15, 16]})
```

I want to get all combinations of 'colA', 'colB', 'colC' and 'colD' and calculate sum for each combination. I can get all combinations using itertools

```
cols = ['colA', 'colB', 'colC', 'colD']
all_combinations = [c for i in range(2, len(cols)+1) for c in combinations(cols, i)]
```

But how can I get the sum for each combination and create a new column in the dataframe? Expected output:

```
id  colA  colB  colC  colD  colA+colB  colB+colC ... colA+colB+colC+colD
a   1     5     9     13    6          14        ... 28
b   2     6     10    14    8          16        ... 32
c   3     7     11    15    10         18        ... 36
d   4     8     12    16    12         20        ... 40
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, select from the frame a list of all columns starting with `col`. Then we create a dictionary using `combinations`, where the keys are the names of the new summing columns, and the values are the sums of the corresponding columns of the original dataframe, then we unpack them `**` as arguments to the `assign` method, thereby adding to the frame

```
cols = [c for c in df.columns if c.startswith('col')]
df = df.assign(**{'+'.join(c):df.loc[:, c].sum(axis=1) for i in range(2, len(cols) + 1) for c in combinations(cols, i)})
print(df)
```

```
  id  colA  colB  colC  colD  colA+colB  colA+colC  colA+colD  colB+colC  colB+colD  colC+colD  colA+colB+colC  colA+colB+colD  colA+colC+colD  colB+colC+colD  colA+colB+colC+colD
0  a     1     5     9    13          6         10         14         14         18         22              15              19              23              27                   28
1  b     2     6    10    14          8         12         16         16         20         24              18              22              26              30                   32
2  c     3     7    11    15         10         14         18         18         22         26              21              25              29              33                   36
3  d     4     8    12    16         12         16         20         20         24         28              24              28              32              36                   40
```